# How do I access custom TextBox field in a default Blog Post document type?

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have added a Textbox field named `excerpt` to the default Blog Post document type in Umbraco 7. Umbraco reports a compilation error when it tries to access the data in that excerpt field.

**In my template**:

```
@{
    var recentblogpost = Model.Content.Site().FirstChild("BlogPostRepository").Children("BlogPost").Last();
}

@recentblogpost.Name, @recentblogpost.excerpt
```

Getting `@recentblogpost.Name` or `@recentblogpost.Url` succeeds. Only the custom fields I add such as `@recentblogpost.excerpt` don't succeed. I have tried switching the capitalization case to `@recentblogpost.Excerpt`.

**The error which is reported**:

`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent' does not contain a definition for 'excerpt' and no extension method 'excerpt' accepting a first argument of type 'Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet worked. `@recentblogpost["excerpt"]`